# Error when using iron:router with Meteor 0.9.3.1

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am experimenting with Meteor and iron:router. I git cloned the examples from https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git. I then cd-ed into samples/basic, and ran meteor update and meteor. My meteor version is 0.9.3.1

When I navigated to the website an error is displayed in console and the page is empty. The error is as below:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Couldn't find a template named "/" or "". Are you sure you defined it?
at null._render (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?32038885cb1dad7957291ffebfffcb7f8cd57d20:239:17)
at doRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1853:25)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1795:16
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:2029:12)
at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1794:18)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:476:11)
at Blaze.View.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1793:19)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1847:10 debug.js:41
```

Can someone kindly advise what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you have this issue is there is a discrepancy between the `iron-router@1.0.0-pre-x` (like a Beta for 1.0) and the currently in use 0.9.x version of iron router.

The old notation for defining a route for `http://localhost:3000/route`, for the template `route` would be as follows:

```
Router.route("route", { path : '/' });
```

However in the new version, which is currently on github on devel (which I presume the examples are based on is as follows):

```
Router.route("/", function() {
    this.render("route");
});
```

The problem is using the notation on the bottom would lead to the error `Couldn't find a template named "/"` since the first param of the `Route.route` is now a path instead of a template.

The way to fix this is to either use the pre-release version of iron router (the version string can be found in the package.js file on github):

```
meteor remove iron:router
meteor add iron:router@1.0.0-pre3
```

Or to use the old notation by looking at an example bundled with a release on github instead of the `devel` branch like this one: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/v0.9.2-rc0

Comment: Thanks a bunch Akshat. It works as you have mentioned when I downgraded to iron:router@1.0.0-pre3

Comment: I am also facing another challenge now. Once I move my templates and Router.route definitions into child folders such as into '/client/core', the application does not route correctly anymore.

Comment: @3thanZ this router version is actually still being worked on. It requires routes to be set up on the server side and client side (root folder) for 404s to work correctly. If you want to use the current version of iron router you would need to *downgrade* to 0.9.3

Comment: Thanks @Akshat, I got it working after using the latest iron:router using the method that you mentioned above: Router.route("route", { path : '/' });