# Meteor app works fine locally but iron:router error shows when it works in AWS EC2

Tags: git, meteor, amazon-ec2

I have a meteor application, and developing and testing with localhost:3000. Everything works fine. No errors in terminal (server) and console.log (browser).

But after I git pull the app in EC2 instance, and running the same meteor, the iron:router error shows randomly in the page:

Couldn't find a template named "layout" or "layout". Are you sure you defined it?

I followed the two solutions from 
1) [Iron Router inside package: cannot find template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216254/iron-router-inside-package-cannot-find-template)
2) [Error when using iron:router with Meteor 0.9.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239413/error-when-using-ironrouter-with-meteor-0-9-3-1)

But every first time when I load the page, I still get the issue.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: This issue happens mostly in Chrome, and be fine in FF and IE. After one refresh in Chrome, everything goes well. But, if I leave the page open in FF for, saying 2 hours, then refresh in FF, "Couldn't find a template..." page shows in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Try: meteor reset. WARNING: this will erase your DB.

Maybe you add to git .meteor/local folder that contains file that shouldn't be versioned.

I suggest you to use mup package from Arunoda to deploy your apps.

Comment: Thanks for help. I did use meteor reset. It can solve the 2-hour-blank-page issue  but he first try on Chrome still show "Couldn't find ..." issue. I was failed on meteor up so I tried the meteor run on instance.